# display iPhone contacts using system framework in ios

Tags: objective-c

In my app if I tap one button I need to display all the phone contacts like whatsapp... How to acheive this with AddressBook framework? Or can we use any other frameworks to display all the device contacts...

Comment: [there are tons of examples online..](https://www.google.com.kw/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW556KW556&espv=2&q=import+contacts+programmatically+ios&oq=import+contacts+programmatically+ios&gs_l=serp.3...8379.16207.0.16443.9.9.0.0.0.0.208.795.0j2j2.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..5.3.585...0i22i30k1j0i7i30k1j0i7i5i30k1.1GZZr9YVwOo) please search before you post here..

Comment: Yeah it works!!! Thanks

Comment: @SivagamiSundari if my answer helpful for you then please give it correct mark so it will help for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can fetch the contact using the contact framework: following the step->

1. Add the contact.framework and contactUI.framework in your app bundle.
2. Add the two file in your .h file:

   #import Contacts/Contacts.h
   #import ContactsUI/ContactsUI.h
3. Add the flowing code

```
         -(void)loadContactList 
        {
           
    
     @try {
         
    
           CNAuthorizationStatus status = [CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts];
    
                   
         if( status == CNAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == CNAuthorizationStatusRestricted)
    
    {
    
                    NSLog(@"access denied");
    
                 }
                else
                {
                    //Create repository objects contacts
                    CNContactStore *contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc] init];
                    
                    //Select the contact you want to import the key attribute  ( https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Metadata_Keys )
                    
                    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactViewController.descriptorForRequiredKeys,nil];
                    
                    // Create a request object
                    CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];
                    request.predicate = nil;
                    
                    [contactStore enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest:request
                                                              error:nil
                                                         usingBlock:^(CNContact* __nonnull contact, BOOL* __nonnull stop)
                     {
                         // Contact one each function block is executed whenever you get
                         NSString *phoneNumber = @"";
                         if( contact.phoneNumbers)
                             phoneNumber = [[[contact.phoneNumbers firstObject] value] stringValue];
                         
                         NSLog(@"phoneNumber = %@", phoneNumber);
                         NSLog(@"givenName = %@", contact.givenName);
                         NSLog(@"familyName = %@", contact.familyName);
                         NSLog(@"email = %@", contact.emailAddresses);
                         
                         
                         [contactList addObject:contact];
                     }];
                }
                
          
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                NSLog(@"Exception:%@",exception.reason);
            }
            }
```

Call this method in view did load or view did appear.